# How to put a Growl alert if an input field isn't filled up by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a formular that a user should put text into the input fields, but one of the fields is needed to be filled in and can't be left with a null content. I want that as soon as the user clicks on the sumbit button, a growl appears to tell him that he needs to fill that field, and the sumbit is not sent to the back-end.

Comment: Start by reading up on how to do form validation with javascript. Stackoverflow is not a *"how to"* tutorial service. This question is far too broad as outlined in the [help]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the real thing i want to know is how to show that "Growl" notification..

Comment: There are lots of scripts for doing that ... easily found in a web search. Again that is asking *"how to"* do a general task

Comment: What do you mean by "growl"? Do you mean you want to synthesize a growling voice that tells the user what they did wrong? Or do you just want to have a normal alert with a growl playing in the background? You should probably [edit] your question to explain more clearly what you mean by "growl appears to tell him..."